# Solve for the heights in a sinusoidal function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

A Ferris wheel has a radius of 10 m and rotates at a rate of one revolution every 48 s. At the bottom of the ride, the passenger is 2 m above the ground. You start your ride from the bottom of the wheel.

At what times is your height 9 m above the ground? Write your answer correct to the nearest second.

Comment: What attempt have you made to solve this? You could start by drawing a diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
The radius is equal to the amplitude and you know that you have to add 12 to the overall function to make the lowest point equal to 2. You can also you the 48 seconds to account for the period.